# Intro to Discrete Structures $\;\lnot A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Im trying to use propositional logic to break this down but i have no clue. i know about the rule that if a wff ends in form `....implies (a implies b)`, the a can be added to the hypothesis in order to only get `b`. but in my problem ~A implies (A implies B) and my following hypothesis are `~A` and `A`. i do conjunction to get `~A and A` but that gets me no where. how am i supposed to get to B as the result?

Comment: What are you saying?

Comment: Extremely confusing.

Comment: what am i supposed to do with this? theres only two hypothesis, both being the letter a and im supposed to do some rule to get b? im trying to prove that the above is in fact a tautology by propositional logic using inference and equivalence rules, synologies and such

Comment: What is a wff?.

Comment: A well formed formula.

Comment: You have $\lnot$A and A as hypotheses, so you only need to use modus ponens twice.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align} \lnot A \rightarrow (A \rightarrow  B) &\equiv (\lnot A \land A) \rightarrow B \\ \\ & \equiv \text{False} \rightarrow B \\ \\ & \equiv \text{True}\end{align}$$

Recall that in an implication, if the antecedent is false, the implication as a whole is true, regardless of the truth value of the consequent, in this case, of $B$.

In summary, $\lnot A \rightarrow(A \rightarrow B)$ is a *tautology*: always true, regardless of the truth-values of its variables.

Comment: i rememeber that from implication. but in this case what woul dbe the antecedent. thanks though

Comment: The antecedent is $(\lnot A \land A)$, which is necessarily false: $A$ and $\lnot A$ cannot both be true: hence the antecedent is false.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $\lnot$A, and [$\lnot$A$\rightarrow$(A$\rightarrow$B)], then by modus ponendo ponens (or modus ponens or detachment) you then may infer (A$\rightarrow$B).

Since you have A also, and now you have (A$\rightarrow$B), then you may infer B by modus ponendo ponens.